# Parse getting images from server (getDataInBackground not working)

Tags: ios, parse-platform, swiftui

I am new to coding.
Trying to append images from Parse to a `[UIImage]` but get the error "Cannot convert value of type `PFFileObject` to expected argument type `UIImage`.
How can I convert the `PFFile` to a `UIImage`?

```
@Published var profileManageImages =  [UIImage]()

ForEach(uploadMedia.profileManageImages, id: \.self) { picture in
     Image(picture)

func refreshSideScroll() {
    let currentUser = PFUser.current()
        
    let query = PFQuery(className: "Photos")
    query.whereKey("uploadedBy", equalTo: currentUser!)
    query.limit = 8
    query.findObjectsInBackground(block: { (objects: [PFObject]?, error: Error?) in
        if error == nil {
             for images in objects!{
             self.profileManageImages.append(images["image"] as! PFFileObject)
             }
        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need still to fetch data of image from `PFFileObject`, like

```
query.findObjectsInBackground(block: { (objects: [PFObject]?, error: Error?) in
    if error == nil, let objects = objects {
         for object in objects {
            if let file = object["image"] as? PFFileObject {
               file.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock{(data: NSData?, error: NSError?) in
                 if error == nil, let data = data, let image = UIImage(data: data) {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async  {
                        self.profileManageImages.append(image)
                    }
                }
            }
             
         }
    }
})
```

Comment: Thank you! I will try this out.